# Getting the "zero value" corresponding to a given value

Tags: python, python-2.7, types, zero

In Python 2.7, being given a value of a built-in type `t`, how can I calculate the "zero value" of `t` without enumerating all the cases?

```
def zero_value(x):
    if isinstance(x, dict):
        return dict()
    if isinstance(x, int):
        return 0
    if isinstance(x, bool):
        return False
    if x is None:
        return None
    # ...

assert zero_value({1: 2, 3: 4}) == {}
assert zero_value(3) == 0
assert zero_value(None) == None
assert zero_value(True) == False
```

Not sure if "zero value" is the right term here, since I could not find any answer on SO or Google... I've skimmed [this list of magic methods](http://www.rafekettler.com/magicmethods.html) without more success.

Comment: There is no guarantee a type even has a useful concept of "zero value". For example, `file`, `defaultdict`, and `numpy.ndarray` have no reasonable "zero value".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For most of the types you can simply call the constructor with no arguments.

```
def zero_value(x):
    if x is None:
        return None
    return type(x)()
```

Handle the rest manually.

Comment: Much simpler than I thought. Thanks!

Comment: Aside: In Python 3 you can also construct instances of `NoneType` so `return type(x)()` would work even when `x is None`. This is *not* true for Python 2.7 though.